# iOS Appirater works when debug enabled, not disabled

Tags: ios, appirater

I set

APPIRATER_DAYS_UNTIL_PROMPT 0
APPIRATER_USES_UNTIL_PROMPT 5

and have
[Appirater appLaunched:YES];
[Appirater appEnteredForeground:YES];

in my delegate class.

However, after testing on a development device, and reopening the app 5 times, I always get the prompt to rate the app.
Anyone have any pointers on where I should look to fix this?

Comment: Simply remove your app from the device, clean and build your target and try again. Perhaps you have clicked *No, thanks* before.

Comment: It is prompting always... that is the issue... my bad, edited the question, It made me frustrated...

Comment: I still don't understand you question. If it's in debug mode it always promts, if debug is set to NO then it should appear only the 5th time you open the app.

Comment: Can you clarify the problem @rekire? Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Skeater I just removed the footer from this question. However I have no idea about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show us the how you've set up the Appirater script in your delegate? Do you still have this line in your code?

```
[Appirater setDebug:YES];
```

That causes the rating to open every single time the app runs, so you can check how it looks. Make sure that line has been removed.